# R Filter to remove rows within map function

Tags: r, dictionary, filter, purrr

I am simulating events from the following `data` table using the `map` function and filtering `zero` value events.

However I would like to filter within the `map` function, thereby reducing the size of the `event` table that gets created.

The following simulates `events` based on the Poisson distribution for a given mean (it includes `freq = 0` but to manage memory I don't want these):

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1); n <- 10
data <- tibble(locid = seq(5), exp = 2)

event <- data %>% 
    mutate(freq = map(exp, ~rpois(n, .x))) %>%
    mutate(freq = map(freq, ~ data.frame(freq = .x, sim = seq_along(.x)))) %>%
    unnest()
```

I can then filter with `event %>% filter(freq != 0)`. How can I slot this into the `map` function please? This will make the memory footprint a lot more manageable for my code. Thank you!

Comment: Are the `sim` numbers important?

Comment: Yes, it acts as the event index. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be `discard`

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
    mutate(freq = map(exp, ~rpois(n, .x) %>%
                           discard(. == 0) %>%
                           tibble(freq = ., sim = seq_along(.)))) %>% 
    unnest
```

---

if 'sim' should be based on the original sequence, then create a `tibble` of 'rpois' output and the sequence of the elements, then do the `filter` within `map`

```
data %>% 
    mutate(freq = map(exp, ~ rpois(n , .x)  %>% 
                               tibble(freq = ., sim = seq_along(.))  %>% 
                               filter(freq != 0))) %>%
    unnest
```

Or using `mutate` in between

```
 data %>% 
     mutate(freq = map(exp, ~  tibble(freq = rpois(n, .x)) %>% 
                                  mutate(sim = row_number()) %>% 
                                  filter(freq != 0))) %>%
     unnest
```

Comment: This is my first thought, but the OP said `sim` number is important. This approach change the `sim` numbers, not from 1 to 10.

Comment: @www Thanks for spotting that.  I updated with `filter`

Answer (score 2):

Here is one idea. No need to create `data.frame`. Create `list` with `freq` and `sim`, and then `unnest` them.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1); n <- 10
data <- tibble(locid = seq(5), exp = 2)

event <- data %>% 
  mutate(freq = map(exp, ~rpois(n, .x)),
         sim = map(freq, ~which(.x > 0)),
         freq = map(freq, ~.x[.x > 0]))%>%
  unnest()
event
# # A tibble: 45 x 4
#    locid   exp  freq   sim
#    <int> <dbl> <int> <int>
#  1     1     2     1     1
#  2     1     2     1     2
#  3     1     2     2     3
#  4     1     2     4     4
#  5     1     2     1     5
#  6     1     2     4     6
#  7     1     2     4     7
#  8     1     2     2     8
#  9     1     2     2     9
# 10     2     2     1     1
# # ... with 35 more rows
```